# Always get 0 when using QMediaPlayer.duration()

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

Here is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QMediaContent, QMediaPlaylist
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget


class Demo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Demo, self).__init__()
        self.playlist = QMediaPlaylist(self)
        self.player = QMediaPlayer(self)
        self.player.setPlaylist(self.playlist)

        self.playlist.addMedia(QMediaContent(
            QUrl.fromLocalFile('mypath')))
        self.playlist.addMedia(QMediaContent(
            QUrl.fromLocalFile('mypath')))
        self.playlist.setPlaybackMode(QMediaPlaylist.Loop)
        self.playlist.setCurrentIndex(1)

        self.player.setVolume(80)
        self.player.play()

        self.player.durationChanged.connect(self.print_durantion)
        print(self.player.duration())  # 0

    def print_durantion(self, d):
        print(d)                       # never printed


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    demo = Demo()
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I'm trying to get the duration of the file, but always get 0. It says in QtAssistant that the value may not be available when initial playback begins and tells us to use durantionChanged to receive status notifications.

But how will the durationChanged signal be emitted if duration is always 0(the value d is never printed)?

Is there any way to get duration when a media file is played? Any helps would be appreciated. (I tested the above code on MacOS)

Comment: Works fine for me on linux with qt-5.12.1/pyqt-5.11.3 and a random mp3. What platform are you testing on, and what specific verions of qt5 and pyqt5 are you using? What kinds of media are you trying to play? (PS: it probably won't make any difference, but try connecting `durationChanged` *before* calling `play()`).

Comment: I tested it on MacOS, the durationChanged signal is never emitted. It works fine on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You are attaching the `durationChanged` signal after you select the media. This signal is triggered only once as the media is selected and not after.

If you place it before `setCurrentIndex` it should work as expected, but you may need to attaching it before linking the playlist.

Here is a working [mediaplayer demo application in PyQt5](https://github.com/mfitzp/15-minute-apps/blob/master/mediaplayer/mediaplayer.py) to confirm the signal works for your current PyQt5 install.

Comment: sorry, but it's still not available on Mac.

Comment: @mfitzp sir the example which u shared helped me clear my confusion thank you sir.