# Can not change media using setSource() in pyside6

Tags: python, qt, qthread, pyside6, qmediaplayer

I have some video clips named 0.mp4, 1.mp4, 2.mp4... and I am using QMediaPlayer in PySide6.
I want to write a media player which can play videos one by one. At the end of each video clip, I use the 'setSource()' function to transition to the next clip. But the mainwindow stuck every time I execute setSource() in slot function.
I guess it is somewhat related to threads, so I tried changing source in a new thread. But it seems to only complete one switch, and have no response at the end of the 1.mp4.

**1. I tried writing setSource() in an ordinary function:
**

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtCore import Slot, QUrl
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PySide6.QtMultimedia import QAudioOutput, QMediaPlayer
from PySide6.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self._audio_output = QAudioOutput()
        self._player = QMediaPlayer()
        self._player.setAudioOutput(self._audio_output)

        self._video_widget = QVideoWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self._video_widget)
        self._player.setVideoOutput(self._video_widget)
        self.video_now = 0

        self._player.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile("./{}.mp4".format(self.video_now)))
        self.video_now += 1
        self._player.play()

        self._player.mediaStatusChanged.connect(self.change_source)

    @Slot()
    def change_source(self):
        self._player.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile("./{}.mp4".format(self.video_now)))
        self.video_now += 1
        self._player.play()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_win = MainWindow()
    available_geometry = main_win.screen().availableGeometry()
    main_win.resize(available_geometry.width() / 3,
                    available_geometry.height() / 2)
    main_win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

mainwindow will be stuck at the end of the 0.mp4.

**2. I tried putting setSource() into a new thread:**

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtCore import Slot, QUrl, QThread
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PySide6.QtMultimedia import QAudioOutput, QMediaPlayer
from PySide6.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget

class source_thread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, func):
        super().__init__()
        self.func = func

    def run(self):
        self.func()
        print("source_thread_finished")

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self._audio_output = QAudioOutput()
        self._player = QMediaPlayer()
        self._player.setAudioOutput(self._audio_output)

        self._video_widget = QVideoWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self._video_widget)
        self._player.setVideoOutput(self._video_widget)
        self.video_now = 0

        self._player.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile("./{}.mp4".format(self.video_now)))
        self.video_now += 1
        self._player.play()

        self._player.mediaStatusChanged.connect(self.source_thread_slot)
        self.thread_source = source_thread(self.change_source)


    @Slot()
    def source_thread_slot(self, play_status):
        if play_status != QMediaPlayer.MediaStatus.EndOfMedia:
            return
        self.thread_source.start()

    def change_source(self):
        self._player.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile("./{}.mp4".format(self.video_now)))
        self.video_now += 1
        self._player.play()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_win = MainWindow()
    available_geometry = main_win.screen().availableGeometry()
    main_win.resize(available_geometry.width() / 3,
                    available_geometry.height() / 2)
    main_win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

the first switch was perfect, but the program didn't response at the end of 1.mp4.

You can download short video clips in [pexel](https://www.pexels.com/videos/) for test, and I'm very grateful if you can give me some suggestions.

Comment: QMediaPlayer (as most Qt classes) is not thread-safe and can only be accessed from the main thread. Besides, there's absolutely no point in using threading for this. Just connect `mediaStatusChanged` to `change_source`, but properly check the received status *and* also update the video id *before* calling `setSource()` again.

Comment: @musicamante can you post an example? It just doesn't work if connect `mediaStatusChanged` to `change_source`. The window will stuck.

Comment: @just_be_happy If you are not the OP, please post a question with a proper [mre] based on your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Check the status, play when media is loaded, set source when end of media is reached.

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self._audio_output = QAudioOutput()
        self._player = QMediaPlayer()
        self._player.setAudioOutput(self._audio_output)

        self._video_widget = QVideoWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self._video_widget)
        self._player.setVideoOutput(self._video_widget)
        self.video_now = 0

        self._player.mediaStatusChanged.connect(self.change_source)

        self._player.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile("./{}.mp4".format(self.video_now)))
        
    def change_source(self, status):
        if status == QMediaPlayer.LoadedMedia:
            self._player.play()
        elif status == QMediaPlayer.EndOfMedia:
            self.video_now += 1
            self._player.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile("./{}.mp4".format(self.video_now)))
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The window won't play second video, and the window is stuck. The code works on your computer?

Comment: @just_be_happy Yes, although I was using PyQt5. I just assumed it would also work with PySide6.

Comment: This will work fine on Linux using PySide6 if the urls are created properly. The correct way to do this is `QUrl.fromUserInput(f'./{self.video_now}.mp4', QDir.currentPath())`, otherwise the relative paths cannot be resolved and the media will not load at all (on Linux, anyway - I'm not sure about other platforms). However, the current code certainly won't work using PyQt5, since the multimedia APIs are completely different in Qt5.

Comment: Obviously, I used `setMedia` when I tried it with PyQt5 (and removed the audio output lines). The rest of it is identical.

Comment: @alec The QtMultimedia API has been dramatically modified so many times since its introduction, with lots of issues and inconsistencies within Qt5 versions, which is why it removed from initial Qt6 releases and almost rewritten from scratch for its late reintroduction. Sorry, but we cannot ignore that aspect, and since the OP (and, probably, who offered the bounty) is asking about Qt6, checking against that version becomes mandatory, you cannot just change a function name and just *assume* that it will work in the same way.

Comment: @alec Besides, the bounty has a quite controversial reason ("Show me how [...] I need code") and also posted an equally [questionable question](//stackoverflow.com/q/77810883). The OP had threading issues, and unfortunately they never cared to reply my comment; for what we know, the reason for the bounty could be partly or completely unrelated to the issue of this post, and we should think before answering such questions/bounties: if they did something wrong, we need debugging details (or a new, valid post); if they just ask for "the code" like this, SO rules suggest that we shouldn't answer.

Comment: As well as the API differences, there are also major differences between the [Qt5 backend](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_5.13_Multimedia_Backends) and the [Qt6 backend](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtmultimedia-index.html#backends). It appears @just_be_happy [may be testing on MacOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54617381/984421), so it may be worth [switching backends](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtmultimedia-index.html#changing-backends) via the `QT_MEDIA_BACKEND` environment variable to see if that changes the behaviour.

Comment: @just_be_happy Please provide full details of the platform(s) you are testing on as well as the *specific* versions of Qt6 you are using. You must also provide a proper [mre] so that others can try to reproduce your problem. Although it's not ideal, I suggest you use something like [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) to do this, so you can give a link to your MRE along with the details asked for above in a comment. If you don't do this, it's unlikely anyone will be able to help you and your bounty will probably go to waste.